# Image to fill a polygonal SVG shape

Tags: html, css, svg

I know this topic has been posted before, but please read through before marking duplicate.
This is a 2 part question.

I am trying to fill a **hexagonal SVG** shape with an image. What I want is for the image to fully cover the hexagonal area, whether it has to stretch or compress it self in order to do so. So far, I have only been able to accomplish this with a  fixed width image, and that too, having some kind of padding around its sides.

I have searched for this on other questions, but first off, they are not hexagons, secondly, the code provided in them does not help in filling the hexagon completely. Here is my code and snapshot.

```html
<a href="/bhive/business/index/8">
<svg style="width:117px;height:97px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<defs>
 <pattern id="img8" height="100" width="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <image preserverAspectRatio="none" height="100%" width="200%" x="-25"
 xlink:href="images/my-store.gif">
 </pattern>
</defs>
<polygon style="stroke: #999DA3;" fill="url(#img8)" 
points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25">
</svg> 
</a>
```

[image: Snapshot of the hexagon]

The second part is, that I want this hexagon to be responsive. How can I make it responsive, such that it resizes according to the browser window?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all remove height, width and x attribute from image tag. Set 100% height and width in pattern and patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox".

```html
<svg>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern1" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Gl%C3%BChwendel_brennt_durch.jpg/399px-Gl%C3%BChwendel_brennt_durch.jpg" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <polygon style="stroke: #999DA3;" fill="url(#pattern1)" points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Sovon,
I just did that. Now I see an empty Hex Shape. The image is gone.

Comment: That's may be because of wrong image path. Anyway, I'm updating the answer with some changes.

Comment: Ok, that worked. Just one bit of an issue, it (the whole svg) is not centered anymore. previously it was centered. Also, can you please guide me how I can make this svg a bit taller?

Comment: Not sure why you're not getting it centered. To make the svg taller, you need to change the polygon points value. Every point is described with their x and y value and points are in clockwise sequence.

Comment: easier to use a scale transform than alter every polygon point.

Comment: It worked, but in my case BUT I had to leave width and height, otherwise there was no fill happening.